# Find all permutation of a string with certain position unchanged

Tags: algorithm, recursion, permutation, depth-first-search, backtracking

Given a String of words, say "OhMy", keep the uppercase letter fixed(unchanged) but we can change the position of lower case letter. Output all possible permutation.

eg. given "OhMy" it should output [ "OhMy", "OyMh"]

Here is what I did:

```
    public static List<String> Permutation(String s){
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0){
        return res;
    }
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(s);
    List<Character> candidates = new ArrayList<Character>();
    List<Integer> position = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c) && Character.isLowerCase(c)){
            candidates.add(c);
            position.add(i);
        }
    }
    boolean[] occurred = new boolean[candidates.size()];
    helper(res, path, candidates, position, 0);
    return res;
}

public static void helper(List<String> res, StringBuilder path, List<Character> candidates, List<Integer> position, int index){
    if (index == position.size()){
        res.add(path.toString());
        return ;
    }
    for (int i = index; i < position.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < candidates.size(); j++){
            path.setCharAt(position.get(i), candidates.get(j));
            char c = candidates.remove(j);
            helper(res, path, candidates, position, index+1);
            candidates.add(j, c);
        }
    }
}
```

for input "Abc"
it will have result [Abc, Acb, Acc, Acb]
Essentially, the outer loop is iterating every possible position, inner loop tries every possible candidates at each possible position.
I don't know why it has duplicates li "Acc, Acb"

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the main point of your implicit question is how to efficiently enumerate all permutations of a given set, which you can read about online (there are several methods). If you can enumerate all permutations of the indices of lower case letters, then it's pretty straightforward to do book keeping and merge each permutation of lower case letters with the original unchanged set of upper case letters, respecting the positions of the upper case letters, so you can output your strings. If you're having difficultly with that part, update your question and someone should be able to help you out.